# Looking for help with derivation of the Method of Transformation of random variables

Tags: random-variables

The question stems from section '30.6.2 *Continuous random variables*' of Riley Hobson and Bence (Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering). They are deriving the following:

*If $X$ is a continuous RV, then so too is the new random variable $Y = Y (X)$. The probability that $Y$ lies in the range $y$ to $y + \mathrm dy$ is given by*

$$g(y) \mathrm dy = \int_{\mathrm dS} f(x) \mathrm dx$$

*where $\mathrm{dS}$ corresponds to all values of $x$ for which $Y$ lies in the range $y$ to $y + \mathrm dy$.*

I get this part. In the next part I'm having trouble with following their steps from the integrals and I'm not sure if I'm just being silly as I'm quite rusty.

*Once again the simplest case occurs when $Y (X)$ possesses a single-valued inverse $X(Y )$. In this case, we may write*

$$g(y) \mathrm dy = \left| \int_{x(y)}^{x(y+\mathrm dy)}f(x')\mathrm dx' \right|= \int_{x(y)}^{x(y) + |\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}| \mathrm dy)}f(x')\mathrm dx' $$

*from which we obtain*

$$g(y) = f(x(y)) \left| \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy} \right| $$

So I get the expansion of $x(y + \mathrm dy) \approx x(y) + \left| \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy} \right| \mathrm dy$ but then that coming out of the integral I cant seem to follow! Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
It seems like its quite similar to just a change of integration variables where as $x(y)$ t.f. $\mathrm dx = \mathrm dy \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}$ and then $x(y)$ in $f$ goes to $f(x(y))$ but then the integral out front still bothers me!

EDIT 2:

I think I got it, would be **great if someone could verify**.

From the definition
$$f'(x)=\frac{\mathrm df(x)}{\mathrm dx} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} $$

therefore if we consider above the indefinite integral of $f(x')$ as a function $g$, when we put in the limits we get $g \big(x(y) + |\frac{dx}{dy}|dy \big) - g(x(y)$ which can be written as

$$\begin{align} \frac{g \big(x(y) + |\frac{dx}{dy}|dy \big) - g(x(y) }{|\frac{dx}{dy}|dy} \left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|dy &= \frac{dg}{dx} \left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|dy \\ 
&= f(x(y)) \left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|dy \end{align}$$

This doesn't sit truly well with me, feels a bit like physics maths not real maths!

Edit 3:

$$ \int_x^{x+\Delta x} f(u)\mathrm du \approx f(x)\Delta x$$

if $\Delta x$ is small

Solved cheers was being very rusty!

Comment: I think you may check Theorem 7.1, A FIRST COURSE IN PROBABILITY, Sheldon Ross, which should be the precise statement of your question.

Comment: Hi @Captuna I've seen this alternative derivation and its a lot easier to follow! I'm still interested in figuring out what i'm missing from the above question also though

Answer (score 0):

Solved! See edit three

'Edit 3:

$$ \int_x^{x+\Delta x} f(u)\mathrm du \approx f(x)\Delta x$$

if $\Delta x$ is small

Solved cheers was being very rusty!'